# What should I do when there are multiple inputs in seq2seq model?

Tags: python, nlp, seq2seq

I have three input text sequences, together to generate a target sequence. I want to encode three inputs independently. What is the correct way to do that? Is the following way work?
Each input goes into an Input layer, an Embedding layer and an LSTM layer, then concat them together use bi-LSTM again as the encoder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your data look like. If your input is just text, it is probably fine to concatenate all the inputs as strings and separate the inputs by a special token (the way BERT uses the `[SEP]` token to separate two input sentences). Even though BERT is a Transformer, there is no reason this should not work with LSTMs.

If you don't use attention, you can do several encoders and concatenate (and perhaps project) the output states to initialize the decoder as you suggest in the question.

If you want to use attention, it gets a little bit trickier, but there are ways how doing attention over multiple inputs. [Hierarchical attention](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P17-2031.pdf) is usually a good choice.